# Breakpoint on a specific change

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I'm looking for a place in my C# program where a certain property of a known object instance changes its value. It's about a `Count` property of some collection that ends up with 2 items where it should only be 1. I can see where the first item is added to the collection, but I don't know where the second comes from. The program processes a number of other things and I can't step through each of them. When the function is finished, the `Count` property for the interesting instance returns 2.

Setting a breakpoint on the place where I do add items to such collections doesn't help. The condition I use never triggers again. Leaving the condition away is too much noise to handle.

I've tried adding a function breakpoint when `$1.Count` changes but as soon as I click anywhere in that dialog window, the condition is removed again. It seems like a bug in Visual Studio 2015. `$1` will be the object ID that I assign when the first item is added to the collection. I now want to capture the second item being added. Using `$1` in the watch panel does work, and it's in fact the way how I can see the `Count` value of the interesting instance after the function has finished.

Does anybody know a way to set a breakpoint on such an event?

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap that specific collection in a proxy object and hijack the call to `Add` in C#. There, you can check for the current `Count` and eventually call `Debugger.Break();`.

If your collection implements `IList`, you could just write an own implementation of that and forward all calls to an inner list instance. This makes adding hooks or breakpoints for specific situations much easier.

Comment: That's a lot of work. Also the collection is used anywhere in a complex library, I'm not sure I'll do it right. I'd prefer a direct debugging feature over rewriting my code.